# Subcategories On Category Page Magento 1.9.2.2

Tags: ce-1.9.2.2

I'm using this code to show subcategories on the category page. I was working fine in 1.9.2.0 but is broken in 1.9.2.2. Does anyone have the updated code?

```
<?php 
$category = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory();
$categories = $category->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'image'))
        ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)
        ->addIdFilter($category->getChildren())
?>
<h2>Choose A Subcategory...</h2>
<ul class="subcategories">
    <?php foreach ($categories as $category): ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo $category->getUrl() ?>"><img src="<?php echo $category->getImageUrl() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($category->getName()) ?>" /><br />
                <span><?php echo $category->getName() ?></span></a>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
<span class="clear"></span>
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the help, but it turned out to be related to a bug in Magento 1.9.2.2. http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/issue/index/id/870

Comment: @brentwpeterson Are you running a "no thanks" bot??

Comment: @benmarks SE adds that text automagically. Should I be doing something different when reviewing posts?

Comment: @brentwpeterson Just wondered bc that wasn't a "thank you" answer.

Answer (score 1):

1.9.0.1 working code, goes as deep as you permit it. Give it a try.
I also put some example filters in there for others who read this post.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
             ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
             ->addAttributeToSelect('level')
             ->addAttributeToSelect('entity_id');


function recursion($catId) {
    $cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($catId);

    if ($subcats = $cat->getChildren()) {
        foreach(explode(',',$subcats) as $subCatid) {
            $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($subCatid);
            // put your display code here
            // maybe also "recursion($subCatid);"
            // or "if($_category->getLevel() == 3)"
            // etc...
        }
    }
}

foreach($collection as $cat) {
    $catId = $cat->getId();
    recursion($catId);
}
```

Also try:

```
$currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category');
```

Comment: Thanks - that's put me on a good path, but how do I restrict it to one level deep?

Comment: I altered the answer to go only one level deep.

Comment: You may also wish to add a check for $_category->getIsActive()